# In PySpark, how do I read a specific JSON attribute that has been loaded to a dataframe?

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to get the value of "__delta" from the following JSON schema that has been loaded to a dataframe. How do I do that in Pyspark?

```
root
 |-- d: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- __delta: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- __next: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ABRVW: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ADRNR: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ANRED: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

with the struct type JSON object just select the object with the attribute you want to get.

```
df.select("d.__delta")
```

Comment: Here is what I get returned when I do a print: DataFrame[__delta: string]

Answer (score -1):

How about `df.select($"d.__delta")`